# WL.EncryptedCache in Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

`WL.EncryptedCache` **in Worklight.**

1. Can `WL.EncryptedCache` be created for different worklight application ?
2. If so how many Encrypted boxes it can create for a single device ?
3. If no y it cant create ?

This Question arrised because the worklight makes of use of **Webstorage of HTML** for **EncryptedCache**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cache is created per application, so if you have 2 Worklight applications that in both of them you use WL.EncryptedCache then each app will have its own cache.

This is because every app is sandboxed and do not share the cache of another app.
This is not related to Worklight, but to the way the device works be it Android or iOS, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. EncryptedCache uses the HTML5 local storage to store the data. In iOS it is app level and you can find the cached resources in `Library/Caches/yourBundleId/` `ApplicationCache.db`
2. Depends on your number of apps. each apps has its own size. Once it is reached the level you will get javascript errors
3. You can create more than one EncryptedCache in a single device again it is for per application